# Why laravel deployed on serer throws error: File xxx is not within the allowed path(s)

Tags: php, laravel

Why alravel deployed on my live server is throwing this error? How to solve it please?
Full error:

```
is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(/home/vagrant/Code/PersonalPage/storage/logs) is not within the allowed path(s):
(/nfsmnt/:/data/:/usr/php74/:/usr/bin/:/apachetmp:/tmp/:/var/tmp/:/dev/ura
ndom:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-
Q16/:/usr/local/bin/:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt)
```

Local works fine. This is first try i am deploying laravel on server.

Comment: Look like a permission issue on the server try to create a logs folder inside the storage folder and give the web server permission.

Comment: Which permissions should I give to server

Comment: rwx---r-x  2 uid2026299 gid2026299  4 Oct 19 11:52 logs
-Actual permissions

Comment: Give `775` to the logs folder

Comment: nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a config cache issue, i.e. if you do `php artisan config:clear` it should go away.

One problem might be using calls to the `env` helper outside of the `/config` folder - see [here](https://andy-carter.com/blog/env-gotcha-in-laravel-when-caching-configuration)

But even removing those from my code did not help. Permissions don't seem to matter. I still get the error even after `chmod -R 0777 storage` and the error goes away after config clear without changing any permissions.